# Wso2 bps process hangs without reason

Tags: wso2, bpel

I have simple bpl process with 3 invokes in loop. One of instances hang without any visible reason. So process is in active state but it is not executing any longer. Last logged activity is call to invoke. I search database and find out that both request and response are present in table ode_message and they looks correctly. But output variable from invoke in table ode_xml_data is not filled. There is no logs in bps from time when message arrived. Is any way to find out what happen wrong?

I'm try to use Wso2 BPS 2.1.2

Comment: Start both servers in debug mode and check whether any log message prints during the server hang.

Comment: I have reproduced this error using BPS 3.0.0. It seams that every thing is ok but process hung. I can open this process instance in carbon console and do suspend and resume, then instance start work again. At least until it freezes again. How to run server in debug mode?